# Gnu C++ macro __cplusplus standard conform?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, standards-compliance, std

The Gnu C++ compiler seems to define `__cplusplus` to be `1`

```
#include <iostream> 
int main() {
  std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `1` with gcc in standard c++ mode, as well as in C++0x mode, with [gcc 4.3.4](https://ideone.com/d6jdl), and gcc 4.7.0.

The C++11 FDIS says in *"16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]"* that

> The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the **value 201103L** when compiling a C++ translation unit. (Footnote: It is intended that future versions of this standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value. Non-conforming com-
>   pilers should use a value with at most five decimal digits.)

The old std C++03 had a similar rule.

**Is the GCC deliberatly setting this to `1`, because it is "non-conforming"**?

By reading through that list I thought that I could use `__cplusplus` to check in a portable way if I have a C++11 enabled compiler. But with *g++* this does not seem to work. I know about the `...EXPERIMENTAL...` macro, but got curious why *g++* is defining `__cplusplus` this way.

My original problem was switch between different null-pointer-variants. Something like this:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201100L
#  define MYNULL nullptr
#else
#  define MYNULL NULL
#endif
```

**Is there a simple and reasonably portable way to implement such a switch?**

Comment: Side note: I haven't fully read this thread, but this was acknowledged as a bug in g++ (10 years ago!) and is fixed in 4.7.0: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773

Comment: How about `#ifndef nullptr` `#define nullptr NULL` `#endif` or `#ifdef nullptr` `#define MYNULL nullptr` `#else` `#define MYNULL NULL` `#endif`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This was fixed about a month ago (for gcc 4.7.0). The bug report makes for an interesting read: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773

Comment: Whow, I updateded my svn tree last week, but had not run the test code on *that* compiler. Wait... Yes, you are correct! gcc-4.7.0 from last week: `./define-cplusplus.x 
199711`

Comment: The bug was open for over 10 years... Interesting read indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly this has to do with Solaris 8 causing issues when `__cplusplus` is set as it should. The gcc team decided at the time to support the Solaris 8 platform rather than be compliant in this particular clause. But I noticed that the latest version of gcc ends the Solaris 8 support, and I guess this is a first step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very old g++ bug.

That is, the compiler is not conforming.

Apparently it can't be fixed because fixing it would break something on a crazy platform.

**EDIT**: oh, I see from @birryree's comment that has just been fixed, in version 4.7.0. So, it was not impossible to fix after all. Heh.

Cheers & hth.