# How to introduce nullptr to CDT code analyzer?

Tags: c++, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting bothering code analyzer error in Eclipse CDT. It does not work fine with C++11 features. `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` is defined and compiler flags are set. Library compiles and works fine, though I can't find a way to tell Eclipse that `nullptr` is a keyword! Please don't highlight it.

[image: Stupid Eclipse :)]

I'm using default version of current LTS Ubuntu (12.04). It's Indigo (3.7.2).

Comment: I'm using default version of current LTS Ubuntu (12.04). It's Indigo (3.7.2)

Comment: I am also using 12.04 LTS and I don't have any issues with Indigo or Juno. Although I have turned of the static analyzer completely because it gives me [tons of false positives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13458396/341970), it's practically useless. So long story short, I don't have any better idea than turning of the static analyzer. Sorry... :(

Comment: Please find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support/15098556#15098556

Comment: @ravwojdyla I already do that. Just didn't worked.

Comment: @soroush are you sure that those flags are set for cdt parser not for external compiler?

Answer (score 0):

`Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Settings -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`

You can specify the standard there:

`gcc -std=c++11 ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`

It works fine for me, I'm using Mars however.