# Eclipse CDT Plugin keeps giving inexistent errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I prefer Eclipse as IDE, even though I need a plugin to use it for C++. But somehow the CDT plugin marks errors where none are, like this:

[image: Eclipse CDT doesn't know to_string() method]

It tells me that the `function 'to_string()' could not be resolved`, even though `make all` runs without problems.

I already tried the solutions given in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458396/disable-eclipses-error-discovery-c11-false-positives), but with no effect

Comment: so you did rebuild your index and freshen all your files?

Comment: Thanks, rebuilding the index solved it.

Comment: @MantoshKumar compiling works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rebuild the CDT index. This will remove any wrongly reported errors.