# eclipse cdt can't parse <stdint.h>

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

My eclipse does *red-underline*  to `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, etc... though I included `<stdint.h>` and set preprocessor path!

To know why it happens, I looked in `<stdint.h>`.

```
#ifndef _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#if __STDC_HOSTED__
# if defined __cplusplus && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  undef __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  undef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
# endif
# include_next <stdint.h>        // here
#else
# include "stdint-gcc.h"
#endif
#define _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#endif
```

Um, I think it seems that eclipse can't recognize `#include_next`. But I don't know solution.. Could you give me a advice?

Comment: Is it a C or a C++ project?

Comment: @Ali C. but I guess there's the same problem in C++ project...

Comment: In C++ there is a well-known issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13458396/341970 but in C I don't know. The answer there doesn't seem to apply to your case. Sorry, I cannot help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to avoid `#include_next`, we should tell eclipse that `__STDC_HOSTED__` is `0`. In `Project` > `Properties` > `C/C++ General` > `Path and Symbols`, add `__STDC_HOSTED__` as `0`.

Second, you can see some codes like the following in `stdint-gcc.h`.

```
#ifdef __INT8_TYPE__
typedef __INT8_TYPE__ int8_t;
#endif
```

`__INT8_TYPE__` things are predefined macros of gcc. We must tell eclipse about them as well. So, add all macros from [`gcc -E -dM - < /dev/null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) **except** `__STDC_HOSTED__` which we added before.